# Fetching data using url which is of db and which had multiples folders and files in it and then saving it to zipped python file

Tags: python, url, python-requests, python-asyncio, shutil

Fetching huge data around 60 Gb data using requests module with url which is of db and which has multiples folders and files in it and then saving it to zipped python file.

Right now I am testing with 5 Gb data and using requests to fetch the entire db data(folder and files in it) and then saving it to zipped file which takes around 6 hours using shutil copyfileobj. I tried with async function also but not much decrease in saving the data time .

Need suggestions on what could be best approach for such senerio .

1.tried requests module for fetching and shutil.copyfileobj to save
2 asyn function
3 tried using urllib3

Comment: Have you tried a proper asynchronous client like the one provided by [`aiohttp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html) or [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/)?

Comment: Hi Daniil , aiohttp I have tried and it takes half the amount of time what requests module take for fetching same amount of data . Like if requests takes 6 hours for 5 Gb data then aiohttp takes 3 hours which is also much for us as we want to save the data within maximum one hour .2nd option  httpx not used yet .